# Creating an object that asks the user to enter a desired user id and stores this id

Tags: python

I am trying to create an object that creates user ID's from the input of user. I am learning OOP through this. I need help!!

I tried my best, I'M NEW

```html
class creat:
    def __init__(self, userid):
        self.userid = userid

    def enter(self, show):
        print(userid)
        self.show = show

userid = input("enter user id")
show = print(userid)

creat()
userid.enter()
```

My error is coming up as:

```html
enter user id998
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/singlefawn/Desktop/Our Realm/1997/Programs/random gallery/_sooseow_1_0.py", line 14, in <module>
    creat()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'userid'
998

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hello! Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum. Do not answer to your post with not working trials. Please, answer your own post only to give a proper answer: see [can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Got it thank you , totally new getting the hang of it

Comment: A good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Truly truly truly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `userid` to `Creat` (classes should be UpperCaseStyle in python) when instantiating it, and then you need to properly call the `enter` method.

```
class Creat:
    def __init__(self, userid):
        self.userid = userid
        self.show = None

    def enter(self, show):
        self.show = show

userid = input("enter user id: ")

some_user = Creat(userid) # instantiate Creat with userid
print("user id: {:s}".format(some_user.userid))

some_user.enter("some show info") # enter some show info
print("show: {:s}".format(some_user.show))

print("\nUser Info\nUser: {:s}\nShow: {:s}".format(some_user.userid,some_user.show))
```

You could also put the `input` inside the class init like this:

```
class Creat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.userid = input("enter user id: ") # ask for id here
        self.show = None

    def enter(self, show):
        self.show = show

some_user = Creat() # instantiate Creat without userid
print("user id: {:s}".format(some_user.userid))

some_user.enter("some show info") # enter some show info
print("show: {:s}".format(some_user.show))

print("\nUser Info\nUser: {:s}\nShow: {:s}".format(some_user.userid,some_user.show))
```

Output:

```
enter user id: alice
user id: alice
show: some show info

User Info
User: alice
Show: some show info
```

To have the user input `show` you could do something like this:

```
class Creat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.userid = input("enter user id: ")
        self.show = None

    def enter(self, show):
        self.show = input("what show do you like?: ")


some_user = Creat() # instantiate Creat with userid
print("user id: {:s}".format(some_user.userid))

some_user.enter("some show info") # enter some show info
print("show: {:s}".format(some_user.show))

print("\nUser Info\nUser: {:s}\nShow: {:s}".format(some_user.userid,some_user.show))
```

New Output:

```
enter user id: Alice
user id: Alice

what show do you like?: Bob Newhart
show: Bob Newhart

User Info
User: Alice
Show: Bob Newhart
```

Comment: Wow that looks clean is there a shorter method for this?

Comment: The prints are unnecessary, and the second version put the input inside the class too, which makes it a bit more concise.

Comment: I’m trying to understand the show some info piece I realized I wrote the enter part but didn’t need it maybe could show be like a I’d number that the user creates ?

Comment: You'd do that just like entering the `userid`, as in the updated answer. If helpful, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Wow that worked beautifully, thank you so is this user created id always stored, how would I save it to the user that entered it like a form of identification and if they enter their id it will say hello there name. Does this make sense??

Comment: Are you looking for behavior if a repeat user id is entered? I think that could be another question altogether. And you can accept by clicking the green check box.

Comment: How do I follow you on here or be your friend on stack, I created a new one and I will make a new post about the behavior too, I'm  learning little sprout here, I'm searching for the force))

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass `userid` when instanciating your class creat, so you should do

```
creat(userid)
```

also when calling the enter method you should pass the show parameter